# How to pass multiple server values to the web method when using AJAX Toolkit CascadingDropDowns

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax

I need to pass in multiple server values to the web method.

If I pass through a single value in the ContextKey, like this:

```
ContextKey='<%# this.someValue.ToString()%>'”
```

I get the value, no problem.

But as soon as I try passing multiple variables, like this:

```
ContextKey='someKey1:<%# this.someValue1.ToString()%>;someKey2:<%#this.someValue2.ToString()%>'
```

I end up getting the literal string.

I used this post to get the syntax on how to pass multiple parameters: 
http://selftaughtprogrammer.com/2012/11/01/how-to-pass-extra-parameters-when-using-ajax-toolkit-cascadingdropdowns-with-a-database/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attribute values in ASP.NET markup can be either literals, or server-binded snippet, you cannot mix them in arbitrary order. However this is not a big deal, since server-binded snippet gives you everything need to form the necessary value. Say via `string.Format`:

```
ContextKey='<%# string.Format("someKey1:{0};someKey2:{1}", this.someValue1, this.someValue2) %>'
```